# Filter on index in spark rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Is it possible to filter on an specific column value in an RDD
.Eg:

```
[(u'62d45630-587a-4290-91e1-a86fbe019bb5', (Row(process_id=1, event_id=u'62d45630-587a-4290-91e1-a86fbe019bb5', event_type=u'PlannedCustomerChoiceWasUpdated', publishedDate=u'2016-07-27T04:16:13.650Z', tgt_tbl_n=u'raw_plan', subj_area=u'plan', flag=u'R', url=u'http://gbp-router.gapinc.dev:8080/planning-service/planning/buy-plan/planned-customer-choices/a448760d-6d92-4dc9-b04a-7ec22673a158', url_id=u'a448760d-6d92-4dc9-b04a-7ec22673a158'), '{"ts":"2016-07-28T11:54:54.748Z","httpStatus":404,"errors":[{"code":"notFound","message":"Planned Customer Choice with id a448760d-6d92-4dc9-b04a-7ec22673a158 does not exist."}],"requestId":"ugM4CXkgax5qxILq"}', None, u'2016-07-27T04:16:13.650Z', 'N'))]
```

the RDD is in key,value form.I want to filter on the value[4] , i.e 'N'.
Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score -1):

I do not quite understand what you want to accomplish as your question is a little unclear to me but there are different ways to filter on an RDD.

An RDD itself does not have a schema so you cannot filter columnwise here as far as i know. If you want to run SQL queries on an RDD you can turn the RDD into a Dataframe by applying a Schema and using the toDF() function. A Dataframe can then be handled equally to a table in a Database.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds

Another way to filter on an RDD is a filter() function.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#basics

I guess your RDD has the form of a tuple with an Iterable as second value. You could run through the Iterable and filter for all values that do not match your criteria. You could also filter for the last position in your Iterable, given that the syntax of your data is always the same.

Hope that helps!